# Leaflet - Event on tiles loading

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I am currently developing a map-based application and need a way to get notified when `Leaflet` is pulling tiles from the `TileProvider` (which, in my case, is `MapBox`). I read the [Leaflet documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html), especially the part with the [TileLayer](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer). Currently, I am using the following code to attach a `tileload` handler:

```
map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    layer.on('tileload', function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    });
});
```

Is there a better way to get the `TileLayer` of the current map? One problem with this approach is that I hook the handler to all layers (although only `TileLayers` will raise events, it is unclean to hook it too all layers). Or can I attach the handler directly to the map instance somehow?

### Update

I initialize the map with the following `MapBox` code snippet:

```
map = L.mapbox.map( element, '...', mapOptions );
```

This automatically creates a `TileLayer` (and several other layers), attaches them to the `map` object and returns this object for later use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've got a lot of `L.mapbox.TileLayer` instances and you don't want to add the eventhandler manually to each instance like Alexandru Pufan suggests in his answer you could still use a loop and `Object`'s `instanceof` method:

```
map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    if (layer instanceof L.mapbox.TileLayer) {
        layer.on('tileload', function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        });
    }
});
```

After reading your comment on Alexandru's answer i'm guessing you only have one layer, then it would be best to add it manually to the instance, which is possible with `L.mapbox.TileLayer` like this:

```
var layer = L.mapbox.tileLayer(YOUR MAP ID);
layer.on('tileload', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});

var map = L.mapbox.map('mapbox', null, {
    'center': [0, 0],
    'zoom': 0,
    'layers': [layer]
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Why not use tileload event directly on the tile layer, like this:

```
//create a variable to store the tilelayer
var osm = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);

//add the tileload event directly to that variable
osm.on('tileload', function (e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: Because I use `MapBox`, I do not create the `TileLayer` myself, but call the `MapBox API` instead. See my edited post for details.